# pandas - Extend Index of a DataFrame setting all columns for new rows to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I have time-indexed data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'day': pd.Series([date(2012, 1, 1), date(2012, 1, 3)]), 'b' : pd.Series([0.22, 0.3]) })
df2 = df2.set_index('day')
df2
               b
 day             
2012-01-01  0.22
2012-01-03  0.30
```

What is the best way to extend this data frame so that it has one row for every day in January 2012 (say), where all columns are set to `NaN` (here only `b`) where we don't have data?

So the desired result would be:

```
               b
 day             
2012-01-01  0.22
2012-01-02   NaN
2012-01-03  0.30
2012-01-04   NaN
...
2012-01-31   NaN
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 37):

Use this (current as of pandas 1.1.3):

```
ix = pd.date_range(start=date(2012, 1, 1), end=date(2012, 1, 31), freq='D')
df2.reindex(ix)
```

Which gives:

```
               b
2012-01-01  0.22
2012-01-02   NaN
2012-01-03  0.30
2012-01-04   NaN
2012-01-05   NaN
[...]
2012-01-29   NaN
2012-01-30   NaN
2012-01-31   NaN
```

For older versions of pandas replace `pd.date_range` with `pd.DatetimeIndex`.

Answer (score 7):

You can resample passing day as frequency, without specifying a `fill_method` parameter missing values will be `NaN` filled as you desired

```
df3 = df2.asfreq('D')
df3

Out[16]:
               b
2012-01-01  0.22
2012-01-02   NaN
2012-01-03  0.30
```

To answer your second part, I can't think of a more elegant way at the moment:

```
df3 = DataFrame({ 'day': Series([date(2012, 1, 4), date(2012, 1, 31)])})
df3.set_index('day',inplace=True)
merged = df2.append(df3)
merged = merged.asfreq('D')
merged


Out[46]:
               b
2012-01-01  0.22
2012-01-02   NaN
2012-01-03  0.30
2012-01-04   NaN
2012-01-05   NaN
2012-01-06   NaN
2012-01-07   NaN
2012-01-08   NaN
2012-01-09   NaN
2012-01-10   NaN
2012-01-11   NaN
2012-01-12   NaN
2012-01-13   NaN
2012-01-14   NaN
2012-01-15   NaN
2012-01-16   NaN
2012-01-17   NaN
2012-01-18   NaN
2012-01-19   NaN
2012-01-20   NaN
2012-01-21   NaN
2012-01-22   NaN
2012-01-23   NaN
2012-01-24   NaN
2012-01-25   NaN
2012-01-26   NaN
2012-01-27   NaN
2012-01-28   NaN
2012-01-29   NaN
2012-01-30   NaN
2012-01-31   NaN
```

This constructs a second time series and then we just append and call `asfreq('D')` as before.

Comment: Thanks - this is great to fill the holes, but how can I extend to `2012-01-31` (say).

Comment: Hmmh. But if I have multiple holes/gaps in my original time series, then this does not work any more.

Comment: @paul yes my answer is limited in this respect, I cannot think of a more generic method. It would be better to create the DataFrame with all expected values in the first place if you can, I will have a playaround and see if I can come up with something better

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:
First add a `NaN` record on the last day you want, then resample. This way resampling will fill the missing dates for you.

*Starting Frame:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'day': pd.Series([date(2012, 1, 1), date(2012, 1, 3)]), 'b' : pd.Series([0.22, 0.3]) })
df2= df2.set_index('day')
df2

Out:
                  b
    day 
    2012-01-01  0.22
    2012-01-03  0.30
```

*Filled Frame:*

```
df2 = df2.set_value(date(2012,1,31),'b',np.float('nan'))
df2.asfreq('D')

Out:
                b
    day 
    2012-01-01  0.22
    2012-01-02  NaN
    2012-01-03  0.30
    2012-01-04  NaN
    2012-01-05  NaN
    2012-01-06  NaN
    2012-01-07  NaN
    2012-01-08  NaN
    2012-01-09  NaN
    2012-01-10  NaN
    2012-01-11  NaN
    2012-01-12  NaN
    2012-01-13  NaN
    2012-01-14  NaN
    2012-01-15  NaN
    2012-01-16  NaN
    2012-01-17  NaN
    2012-01-18  NaN
    2012-01-19  NaN
    2012-01-20  NaN
    2012-01-21  NaN
    2012-01-22  NaN
    2012-01-23  NaN
    2012-01-24  NaN
    2012-01-25  NaN
    2012-01-26  NaN
    2012-01-27  NaN
    2012-01-28  NaN
    2012-01-29  NaN
    2012-01-30  NaN
    2012-01-31  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Mark's answer seems to not be working anymore on pandas 1.1.1.

However, using the same idea, the following works:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


# get start and desired end dates
first_date = df['date'].min()
today = datetime.today()

# set index
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# and here is were the magic happens
idx = pd.date_range(first_date, today, freq='D')
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

EDIT: just found out that this exact use case is in the docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex

Answer (score 1):

```py
def extendframe(df, ndays):
    """
    (df, ndays) -> df that is padded by ndays in beginning and end
    """
    ixd = df.index - datetime.timedelta(ndays)
    ixu = df.index + datetime.timedelta(ndays)
    ixx = df.index.union(ixd.union(ixu))
    df_ = df.reindex(ixx)
    return df_
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the question since here you know that the second index is all days in January, but suppose you have another index say from another data frame df1, which might be disjoint and with a random frequency. Then you can do this:

```
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(list(df2.index) + list(df1.index)).unique().sort_values()
df2.reindex(ix)
```

Converting indices to lists allows one to create a longer list in a natural way.