# Continue column with average of previous values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, average, moving-average

I have a number of columns all indexed by datetime and I need to project a forecast for some of the columns based on the past n (lets say in this case 4) days.

```
          A  B  C
31-12-201917 19 49
1-1-2020  4  9  2
2-1-2020  2  23 3
3-1-2020  8  23 7
4-1-2020  6  21 4
5-1-2020  5
6-1-2020  5
7-1-2020  5
8-1-2020  5
9-1-2020  5
10-1-2020 5 
11-1-2020 5
```

So the desired output would have the average of the last 4 days as the respective value for that column for each of the future dates (as shown in column A). Note it should only take the last 4 days as opposed to all dates in the dataframe.

I've tried various rolling ave functions but all seem to require a new column!

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by repeating `5` values in the column, I assume it is as simple as filling NaN with a constant value obtained from some averaging, right?

So how about:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c].fillna(
        df[df[c].notna()].tail(4)[c].mean(),
        inplace=True
    )
```

- `.fillna()` simply fills NaN values
- `df[df[c].notna()].tail(4)` gives you the last 4 non-nan days. feel free to change the value of `.tail()`
- `[c].mean()` averages the values for column c

Comment: I think this will most likely be the best solution however in my actual dataframe the data ends at 4-1-2020 (if we're using the example above) so I would need to extend the date range to include N/As... which at the minute I am struggling to do.

Comment: @spcol [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119039/pandas-extend-index-of-a-dataframe-setting-all-columns-for-new-rows-to-nan) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (assuming `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`):

```
days_logged = 5
rolling_days = 4
cols = ['B', 'C']

for col in cols:
    for i in range(days_logged, len(df.index)):
        df[col].iloc[i] =  df[col].iloc[i - rolling_days: i].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution, but it is highly extensible. `df.update` is your saver in these situations.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[17, 19, 49],
                   [4, 9, 2],
                   [2, 23, 3],
                   [8, 23, 7],
                   [6, 21, 24],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""],
                   [5, "", ""]], columns=list("ABC"))

df.index = pd.date_range(start="12-31-2019", end="01-11-2020", freq="D")

def forecast(df):
    last_day = df.iloc[-1]
    new_day = last_day.name + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    new_data = df.loc[last_day.name - pd.Timedelta(days=3):last_day.name, :].mean()
    new_data.name = new_day
    return new_data

num_predict_days = 7
columns_to_predict = ['B', 'C']

available_data = df.shape[0] - num_predict_days
df_to_predict = df.iloc[:available_data, :].loc[:, columns_to_predict]

for i in range(num_predict_days):
    df_to_predict = df_to_predict.append(forecast(df_to_predict))

df.update(df_to_predict)
```